# Python if-then-else loop, am I doing something wrong in my code?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement

The assignment is:
Write a program that will calculate the problem and stop after the condition has been met. This is an IF/THEN/ELSE problem.  a=1  b=a+1  c=a+b 
Condition: If c is less than 5, then the loop will continue; else, it will end.
a will increase by one after every completed loop

My program works, but this doesn't seem like a loop, just individual lines of code, right?

```
a=1
b=a+1
c=a+b
if c == 5:
    print("first ending")
elif c < 5: c=a+b+1
print ("c does not = 5")
if c == 5:
    print ("second ending")
elif c < 5: c=a+b+2
print ("c still does not = 5")
if c == 5:
    print ("third ending")
print("c now = 5")
print(c)
```

The excess print commands were for me to see if it was adding or not.  Not required.  Thanks in advance for any/all help!

Comment: "this doesn't seem like a loop, just individual lines of code, right?"  _Right_

Comment: So why did you not write it as a loop?

Comment: that is where my problem is.  I guess I am just not understanding exactly what a loop is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions call for an `IF/THEN/ElSE` solution.  But, it also calls for a loop.  Since you are looking for a specific piece of data, this would require a sentinel loop.  This means that the loop to use is a `while` loop.

Now, we need to prime our data and then check to see `if` our condition is met.

```
a = 1
b = a + 1
c = a + b
if c < 5:
    #do something
else:
    print("We're done!")
```

As per the instructions, you are to enter into the loop if the condition `c < 5` is met.  Thus, we will replace our `#do something` with our `while` loop

```
while c < 5:
    a += 1
    b = a + 1
    c = a + b
```

Note that the instruction said that `a` will increase by one.  That means that you need to add on to `a` and then use `a` to update your other variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop as following to increment value of c by 1 in each step,

```
a=1
b=a+1
c=a+b

while c != 5:
  c += 1

print(c)
```

If you want to use a if statement, you can do the following,

```
a=1
b=a+1
c=a+b

while True:
  if c == 5:
    print(c)
    break
  c += 1
```